# Usages of AssertTrue.List (multipe AssertTrue)

Tags: java, list, bean-validation, assertion

I know the usages of [AssertTrue](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?api=javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue), usually on methods (`@AssertTrue`), with optional message as:

> ```
> @AssertTrue(message="{specificDate.isDateTimeValid.AssertTrue}")
> ```

But what is the usages of [AssertTrue.List](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/validation/constraints/AssertTrue.List.html)?

> Defines several AssertTrue annotations on the same element.

Because we can check `True` with 1 annotation, why would we need such a list? I didn't find any usage of adding multiple `AssertTrue` annotations on method/field

Is it just added to satisfy common practice/pattern/convention?

Comment: If you use various `@AssertTrue` with different `javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue.payload()` metadata, it makes sense to have multiple of them defined in one constraint.

Comment: @ernest_k can you answer with example?

Comment: Haha, I suppose I was making a use case in my mind. After thinking about it, I can only come up with some artificial use cases for this. One technically valid use case is `@AssertTrue(message="cde", groups=Group1.class)` `@AssertTrue(message="abc", groups=Group2.class)` where you call `validate(myBean, Group1.class)` in one case and with `Group2.class` in another. But again, it's the same `isValid()` method being called, which poses the question of why not have 2 methods with two distinct annotations in the first place (different logic in methods seems more sensible as a use case)...